# How to set kafka connector run regularly and resume at the proper offsets?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to use kafka connect to ingest data from the kafka server and move to s3.
However, I am wondering how I can set it to run regularly, eg. once an hour?
and then stop.
Then resume to run for next round at the offset that I stop last time?
How can I store these offsets? How to set these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka connect framework is for continuous streaming from/to kafka . For the requirement you mentioned , it seems you need s3 sink connector unless there is specific need to do in batch fashion. Pls refer to [kafka s3 connector doc](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/s3_connector.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if there is a way to know which one is the latest message that Kafka get when the Kafka connect starts running?

Comment: It depends on the consumer config , you can configure to start from the first available offset of the latest offset

Comment: Okay. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentions, Kafka Connect is not for "once an hour" work.

The alternative, batch, solution is [Apache Gobblin](https://gobblin.apache.org/), which can be [ran on a schedule](http://gobblin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/Gobblin-Schedulers/) to [write files to S3](http://gobblin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/case-studies/Publishing-Data-to-S3/).